# How to send email using python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please help me! i want to make a script in python 3 that sends email to any person but from my local machine. i am a beginner  in python right now that is why most of the scripts i have tried don't work at all. it would be a great help if you also explain what i need to do along with the script. thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: If a beginner have you a book or tutorial to learn from - as these show and explain working code

Comment: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/email-examples.html

Comment: You should also know that you can't send an email from just any machine, you have to use an SMTP server. For example, if you have a Gmail account, Google will let you use their SMTP servers to send email.

Answer (score 5):

How about this short little number.

```
'''
Created on Jul 10, 2012
test email message
@author: user352472
'''
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL as SMTP
import logging
import logging.handlers
import sys
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def send_confirmation():
    text = '''
    Hello,

    Here is your test email.

    Cheers!
    '''        
    msg = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    msg['Subject'] = "test email" 
    me ='yourcooladdress@email.com'
    msg['To'] = me
    try:
        conn = SMTP('smtp.email.com')
        conn.set_debuglevel(True)
        conn.login('yourcooladdress', 'yoursophisticatedpassword')
        try:
            conn.sendmail(me, me, msg.as_string())
        finally:
            conn.close()

    except Exception as exc:
        logger.error("ERROR!!!")
        logger.critical(exc)
        sys.exit("Mail failed: {}".format(exc))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(ch)

    random_ass_condition = True

    if random_ass_condition:
        send_confirmation()
```

Comment: Probably not. I shamelessly used this code from a project where it had more functions and the logging came in handy. I guess you can pull it out, but I opted to leave it in the event it can be re-used.

Comment: I could put together a much more useful class in 30 minutes, with some help from the examples linked above here. But then, the OP wouldn't really learn anything...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following:

- http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/smtplib.html
- http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/email.html

They are very easy to use and should sort basic email messaging

Answer (score 2):

Straight to the point:

```
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL as SMTP
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def send_email(subject, body, toaddr="helloworld@googlegroups.com"):
    fromaddr = "johndoe@gmail.com"
    msg = MIMEText(body, 'plain')
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    server = SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
    server.login(fromaddr, "y0ur_p4ssw0rd")
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

So you can now call it like:

```
send_email(subject, body)
```

Or you could use the third argument to specify an email address:

```
send_email(subject, body, "yourfriend@gmail.com")
```